# Spring jpa configure with yml file and failed with message : no file is active

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, yaml

guys i've met up with a problem when i import the code from my instructor , on his machine it is well,but on my machine it crashes. Here comes the code and the configfile and error logs. thank you in advance.

this is the entity class, through my understanding , there will be no mistake in this area, cause the error log focused on the datasources area.

```
package com.imooc.domain;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
* Created by 廖师兄
* 2016-11-03 23:07
*/
@Entity
public class Girl {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@NotBlank(message = "这个字段必传")
private String cupSize;

@Min(value = 18, message = "未成年少女禁止入门")
//    @NotNull
//    @Max()
//    @Length()
private Integer age;

@NotNull(message = "金额必传")
private Double money;

public Girl() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCupSize() {
    return cupSize;
}

public void setCupSize(String cupSize) {
    this.cupSize = cupSize;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Double getMoney() {
    return money;
}

public void setMoney(Double money) {
    this.money = money;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Girl{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", cupSize='" + cupSize + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", money=" + money +
            '}';
 }
}
```

below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.imooc</groupId>
<artifactId>girl</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>girl</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-
8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

below is my application.yum file, as the reason that i used intellij idea ,so the key word is not likely to be wrong. Here goes the application.yml file.

```
spring:
   datasource:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbgirl
      username: root
      password: root
  jpa:
     hibernate:
       ddl-auto: update
       show-sql: true
```

last and the most important is the log. It shows like this.

```
2017-10-06 10:38:20.687  WARN 395992 --- [           main] 
ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during 
context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ***'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource*** [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-10-06 10:38:20.687  INFO 395992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-10-06 10:38:20.703  WARN 395992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2017-10-06 10:38:20.703  INFO 395992 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

`
```